# Scroll lock doesn't work

Tags: 14.04, keyboard

I recently purchased [Das Keyboard Model S Ultimate Mechanical Keyboard](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003F7WXTG) from Amazon, and scroll lock key doesn't seem to work on Ubuntu, I am running Ubuntu 14.04 currently.

I tested the keyboard on Windows 8.1 as well, on the same computer, and scroll lock key works there. Is anyone else experiencing the same problem?

Comment: I haven't actually seen any applications that would use a scroll lock key, to my knowledge. And mine doesn't work either, not sure why it's not enabled by default

Comment: Yes, that thread has the answer to the problem, by entering `xmodmap -e 'add mod3 = Scroll_Lock'` in terminal. Thanks for pointing it out @ElderGeek. Feel free to close this question I guess, I should have researched the answer better, sorry about that.

Comment: @GeorgeDirac No problem. Glad I could point you in the right direction.